# Аутентификация в веб-службе WCF

Tags: c#, .net

Как проверять аутентификацию в web-service WCF, если при обращении к методу создаётся новая сессия? Или информацию об авторизации нужно хранить в сессии web-сервиса?

Answer (score 1):

Если в конфиге SecurityMode не выставлен в None, то доступ к учётке пользователя осуществляется через `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity`.

Вопрос аутентификации WCF разруливает автоматом. По умолчанию это Cerberos, если есть домен, и NTLM, если нет. Но можно настроить так, чтобы было через сертификаты X509. С помощью `ChannelFactory.Credentials` можно подменить учётку пользователя на клиенте.